# Snowflake: Unload table Data to JSON, how to do without .gz compression?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

> create or replace stage elasticsearch_dev url='s3://s3bucket/ElasticSearch'
> credentials=(aws_role='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:role/role_snowflake')
>
> copy into @elasticsearch_dev/test/SAMPLE.json  from (select
> To_JSON(object_construct(*)) from Sample)  file_format = (type =
> json), overwrite=TRUE;

I'm unloading the sample table to JSON format in s3, when I look into S3 the file is **compressed** as SAMPLE.json_0_0_0.json.gz

The s3 file **should not get compressed**, should be like **SAMPLE.json_0_0_0.json**.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compressing is actually a good practice. I am sure you have a use case not to have compression. I have not tried this yet, but looks like under formatTypeOptions, you can disable compression as below
by setting **COMPRESSION to NONE**

-- If FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = JSON ... )
COMPRESSION = AUTO | GZIP | BZ2 | BROTLI | ZSTD | DEFLATE | RAW_DEFLATE | **NONE**

Answer (score 0):

use the compression=none parameter

It is explained in the Snowflake documentation along with all the other parameters you can use:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#type-json

Comment: Welcome to the site!
You might want to elaborate on your answer: Where and how to use that parameter?